How to print image in entire page in Windows 11
There is this 'Fill to page' option on Windows, but it never works as expected. For instance, if i have an image that is smaller than a page, i'd like it to be zoomed in the page so it occupies all the page size. But as you can see on the image below, even selecting 'Fill page', the image is not 'filled' to the entire page size. Tried also 'Fit to page', but same result. Any workarounds ?



Is the image really smaller than the page or does all the white area belong to the image?

As Bodo said, the whitespace may be a part of the image itself, so it is not scaling. To check for this, use the snipping tool and capture the area in red and then save, print and set that image to fill to page and see if it makes a difference.

@Bodo The image is really small , there is no frame

@Narzard There is no white space in the image, i updated the question showing it

What programs do you use for viewing or printing? What file type is the image? Add its width and heigt to the question. What printer do you use?

I think it is something with the built in windows image viewer. I would open the original image in paint, then File > Print > Page Setup. Change it to Portrait and Fit to: 1 by 1. Save, then check Print > Print preview to see the full size image. I just tried and it was fit to full page correctly.

You can still use the old picture print dialog on Windows, which allows you to properly fill the page.

Right-click the picture file in the File Explorer
(If you don't see a Print option, press the Show more options in the bottom of the menu)
Press Print

In this Print Pictures dialog you should be able to set it to print on a full page, as seen below:


This worked, thanks !

Is there a way to make this print dialog, default system wide ? It's a lot better than the stock one !

Most likley not

Although this has solved it for you I would like to provide an alternative that provides a bit more customization and worked for me.

Using the mspaint Microsoft Paint App

File --> Print --> Page Setup





Playing around with Orientation, Margins, Centering and Scaling will allow you quite a bit of flexibility.
You can preview the actual image under the preview menu after setting up the page.

File --> Print --> Print preview


Extra Feautre: If you wanted to print a "poster" you can also print across multiple pages  with the Fit To Option under Scaling too.

